# $ \int_A \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}} = 0 \implies \int_A \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-h)^{2}}{2}} = 0 $

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to show the following: For all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $h \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\int_A \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}} = 0 \implies \int_A \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-h)^{2}}{2}} = 0.
$$
This seems so easy intuitively, but I don't know how to solve it. Intuitively, as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}$ is a strictly positive continuous function, and the Riemann integral is subsumed into the Lebesgue integral, I may hypothesize that $A$ is "disconnected" at every element of $A$, whatever that is supposed to mean here. The picture in my mind is that that "disconnectedness" carries on to the integral on the right, giving zero. I know this is (definitely) not a proof, not even close, but can anyone provide a nice solution to the above?

For the context of where this question came from, I had this question while doing the exercise:

> For all $h \in \mathbb{R},$ let $N(h, 1)$ be the probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ given by
> $$
> N(h, 1)(A)=\int_{A} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-h)^{2}}{2}} d x
> $$
> Show that the measures $N(h, 1)$ and $N(0,1)$ are equivalent, and compute the corresponding Radon-Nikodym derivatives.

> Proof: For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
> $$
> \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-h)^{2}}{2}}=\exp \left(x h-h^{2} / 2\right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}
> $$
> so $N(h, 1)$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $N(0,1)$.... (The rest of the proof is irrelevant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the integrand is strictly positive, the hypothesis implies that $A$ has measure $0$. The integral of any measurable function over  a set of measure $0$ is $0$. (This is a complete and logically correct proof.)